# Adding non-selectable text tab to Ext.TabPanel?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, tabpanel

I'm trying to create a TabPanel that has a text header just beside the tabs. That is, instead of

`|Tab1|Tab2|Tab3|Tab4|`, I want `Text Here   |Tab1|Tab2|Tab3|Tab4|`

The text shouldn't be selectable as a tab, so how do I do this?

Currently, my TabPanel is this:

```
new Ext.TabPanel({
    id: 'lift-template',
    defaults: {
        items:[
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                store: myStore,
                itemCls: 'my-row',
                itemTpl: '<p><span class="blah">{variable}</span></p>'
            }
        ]
    },
    items: [
        {title:'Week'},
        {title: '1'},
        {title: '2'},
        {title: '3'},
        {title: '4'}
    ]
});
```

How do I add an item that isn't a true tab, or at least disable activation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slighly similar to the answer provided by SeanA, this is the modified one for Sencha Touch (1.1).

[Check out the example](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/39EjA/)

```
/**
 * We will just need to extend the original tabpanel to
 * have the ability to create extra text node in front
 * of all the tabs (Check Ext.TabBar)
 */
var FunkyTabPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {
    initComponent: function() {

        //we need it to initialize the tab bar first
        FunkyTabPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

        //Then we hack in our text node. You can add cls/style too
        this.tabBar.insert(0, {
            text: this.title,
            style: 'color:#fff;'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know you could add external resources like that to jsfiddle. Very nice working example.

Comment: Yes. Spread it, so we could communicate well! Picture talks, nicer than just speak right? :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't try to hack in a label using the functionality of a tab.  All you want is a label, so you can probably look through the source code of `TabPanel` and find a conventient place to add this.

I just looked through the source of `Ext.TabPanel` (Ext 3.3.1), and `onRender` is the method where the tab strip is created, so what I would do is create a custom extension of `Ext.TabPanel`, call it `MyApp.WeeksTabPanel`, and override the `onRender` method to add your label after calling the superclass method.  Looks like you might just add a custom span as the first child of `this.stripWrap`.

Something like this:

```
MyApp.WeeksTabPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.TabPanel, {

    onRender: function() {
        MyApp.WeeksTabPanel.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
        this.stripWrap.insertFirst({tag: 'span', html: 'Weeks:'});
    }

});
```

Comment: The answer looks good but he is asking on behalf of Sencha Touch. I doubt it will work. +1 for the correct usage :)

Comment: Ah, apologies... I just filter for "extjs" and didn't even notice that... I guess I needed to read through the tags :-)